# Spreading values into columns (pivot) sensor events in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm fightig with pivoting some sensor data in padas.

I would like to come from this

```
source_df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                          'sensor_id': ['s1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's1', 's1', 's2', 's2'],
                          'value_type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b',],
                          'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

`time sensor_id value_type  value
0     1        s1          a      1
1     1        s1          b      2
2     1        s2          a      3
3     1        s2          b      4
4     2        s1          a      5
5     2        s1          b      6
6     2        s2          a      7
7     2        s2          b      8`

to this form

```
target_df = pd.DataFrame({'sensor_id': ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's2'],
                          'a': [1, 3, 5, 7],
                          'b': [2, 4, 6, 8],
                          'time': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
target_df
```

`sensor_id  a  b  time
0        s1  1  2     1
1        s2  3  4     1
2        s1  5  6     2
3        s2  7  8     2`

Somehow I expect `pivot` to work... by simply:
`source_df.pivot(columns = 'value_type', values = 'value')` - but it does not create the desired outcome.

In `R` it simply works by

[image]

but I really don't understand how to get the same result in `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (source_df.set_index(['sensor_id','time', 'value_type'])['value']
               .unstack()
               .reset_index()
               .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  sensor_id  time  a  b
0        s1     1  1  2
1        s1     2  5  6
2        s2     1  3  4
3        s2     2  7  8
```

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't imagine padas to be compex like that. `DataFrame.pivot`'s `index` should be doing the job in the first place :-(